# Swift: Segmented Control Break Point

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am doing an app in swift, and I am using a few segmented controls... Everything is working ok except for one segmented control. When I press botton 1 or 2 of it, it crashes and I get this message: (Thread 1 : breaking point 1.1)

```
" UISegmentedCOntrol: 0*790564e0; frame= (20 160; 280 29); opaque= NO; autoresize = RM+NM; layer = <CALayer: 0*79057000>>.
```

The code it's like this:

```
@IBAction func Entrada(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        v1 = 1
        break

    case 1:
        v1 = 2
        break

    case 2:
        v1 = 3
        break

    default:
        break
    }



}
```

In the bottom I have this message:

```
sender  UISegmentedControl  0x79fea3b0  0x79fea3b0
```

`self   ConversorXY.AngulosViewController   0x79fe56f0` `0x79fe56f0`
`$match Int`
`$match Int`
`$match Int`

Strange because I did this segmented control like the others and the others are wirking ok.
And I didn't forget the drag the segmented control to the file...

Does anyone know why does this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove the outlet and add it again.

Comment: DOne that twice. No successs :(

Comment: Have you just set a breakpoint in this method?  Check for the blue flag in the margin.

Comment: Ups. I didn't noticed it :( thanks. A lot. That was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - right click on your UI elements and check for `broken` or `old (unlinked)` connections to your code , remove theme and try again !

2- `IBAction` should be `onValueChanged` event:

```
@IBAction func onSegmentChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

Comment: FOund nothing broken or unlinked :(